# Export an UIImage as a sticker for Messages app

Tags: swift, imessage, ios-stickers, mssticker, msstickerview

I'm trying to export an UIImage as a sticker for Messages app, but I can't find any documentation about this.

I have my project with the **Sticker Pack extension** enabled and see that Xcode created a new **Stickers.xcassets**, every image that I add there manually appears on Messages app to use as a sticker, but how can I save an image programatically there, so the user can create stickers from any image ?

All I can find is information related to creating stickers without doing any code, just shipping an app with predefined images.

```
let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "Test")
```

I know how create a MSSticker from the image file, but after this I don't know how to proceed and make this newly created sticker appear on Messages app.

Answer (score 1):

Stickers are loaded from stickers assets catalog `.xcstickers`.
This catalog is a resource file/folder, that means this is placed inside your bundle. All files inside your bundle are not writable and they have only read permissions. IMO what you need to do is:

- You have to store your users custom images in any one of the sandboxed folders (Documents, Library and temp).
- Read image from this folder and create `MSSticker` from it same way as you did. - `let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "Test")` and add. this sticker to array.
- In your `MSStickerBrowserViewController` you will load stickers from array created in previous step.

Like this

```
override func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
    stickers.count
}

override func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView,
                                 stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
    stickers[index]
}
```

Comment: Ok, this shows a browser view with the stickers that I created.

But I don't understand how showing this view can import them to the Messages app.

This is an example of what I want to do: https://imgur.com/jLkuyo5

Comment: Did you solve this ? Sorry but I can't think of way how to make it work like you wish.